# Starting a new thread and returning the main thread Spring webflux methods subscribeOn

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a Spring Webflux application in which I want to spawn a new Thread for a time consuming operation and as soon as the new thread is spawned return the main thread so that client is not kept waiting

Please note the time consuming method is not a WebClient call but a service layer function call to download files from a content storage. I have defined a CallableTask class as below

```
public class DocumentProcessorCallableTask<T> {

    public Mono<T> execute(Callable<T> task) {
        return Mono.defer(
            () -> Mono.fromCallable(task)
                      .doOnError(throwable ->
                          Mono.error(new 
        ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR))));
    }
}
```

And the method in which I want to spawn a new thread is as below. The method named downloadAndUploadSaveLandsDocuments is the one which makes a call to the content storage to get documents

```
private Mono<MarsTxnResponse> subscribeOnScheduler(MarsTxnResponse rsp, Long clientId) {
    return new DocumentProcessorCallableTask<Mono<MarsTxnResponse>>()
        .execute(() -> downloadAndUploadSaveLandsDocuments(rsp, clientId))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
        .thenReturn(rsp);
```

The problem is that a new thread is created but the webflux code inside downloadAndUploadSaveLandsDocuments is not executed.

It gets executed when I change the above code to below BUT the main thread waits until the newly spawned thread completes which I dont want.
Does subscribeOn and publishOn work only from the context of a Webclient call?

```
return new DocumentProcessorCallableTask<Mono<MarsTxnResponse>>()
        .execute(() -> downloadAndUploadSaveLandsDocuments(rsp, clientId))
        .flatMap(marsTxnResponseMono -> marsTxnResponseMono)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
```

The method which calls the content storage is as below.It does not enter Flux.fromIterable in the first case but does enter it in the second case.

```
public Mono<MarsTxnResponse> downloadAndUploadSaveLandsDocuments(
      MarsTxnResponse rsp, 
      Long clientId) {
    return Flux.fromIterable(rsp.getExpandedWebLtLandList())
                .flatMap(webLtLandFromRequest -> {
                      return downloadDocuments(rsp, webLtLandFromRequest, clientId);
                }).collectList()
                .flatMap(objects -> {
                    return documentAsyncUploadService.uploadFilesIfExists(rsp);
                });
}
```

I am using spring-boot 2.4.13 and spring-boot-starter-webflux version 2.4.13

Comment: both of these will get executed, please provide a small working example that backs up your statement as i cant see anything atm. that will stop your first code from executing. It might not execute as you want as i see a lot of faults in your perception of how webflux should behave. But your statement that the code inside is not run, needs to be backed up with a fully working example please.

Comment: @Toerktumlare Added the function in question whose Flux.iterable is getting not getting executed in the first case but is getting executed in the second case.

Comment: the new code provided does not show how it is executing the above code examples. Im going to repeat myself.... please provide a fully working example, as none of the code you have provided is runnable, and the bottom code does not clearly show how the top code is executed. If you expect us to put effort in, you need to put effort into providing a running code example. Otherwise i wish you good luck. Voted to close until clearer code example is provided.

Comment: @Toerktumlare The above code snippets are part of a bigger application implementation and I have to extract the above into a seperate application if u want a fully working application. I am working on extracting the above code into an application which can be run locally.Please do not close this ticket

Answer (score 0):

Finally the code which worked

```
    return Mono.just(rsp)
        .flatMap(
            marsTxnResponse -> {
              new DocumentProcessorCallableTask<Mono<MarsTxnResponse>>()
                  .execute(() -> downloadAndUploadSaveLandsDocuments(rsp, clientId))
                  .flatMap(marsTxnResponseMono -> marsTxnResponseMono)
                  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                  .subscribe();
              return Mono.just(rsp);
            });
```

The most important thing to add was subscribe() after subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())

Comment: hi MOderators, why is this answer not useful? Should I more details? I have added the changes that worked for me.Also, I have added the code snippets I started with